# Navigation buttons with a CSS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS slider that works for the most part except for two things I cannot figure out. The first being, how to get my slider navigation buttons to work the way I am after. Right now, if you click on one, my `addClass` adds `.active` to all of the buttons instead of only the one clicked on. Along with that I cannot figure out how to associate the slider position with the navigation menu. What I mean is if the user does not click any of the buttons I still want the buttons to show which slide is active.

MY second issue is whenever the buttons are clicked it stops the slide show.

What am I doing wrong in my attempts?

Off-topic, but would it be difficult to transition what I have now to fade in the slides rather than sliding them?

```js
$('.control-button').click(function() {
    button = $(this).attr('id');
    id = button.replace('slide', '');
    pos = (id - 1) * 100;
    $('div#slider figure').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
    $('div#slider figure').removeClass('figure2');
    $('.control-button').addClass('active');
    posStr = '-' + pos + '%';
    $('.figure').css('left', posStr);
});

$('img').click(function() {
    $('div#inner').css('left', '0px');
    $('div#slider figure').addClass('figure2');
    $('div#slider figure').css('animation-play-state', 'running');

})
```

```css
div#slider {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider .figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 400%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: left;
    /*animation: 20s company-slider infinite;*/
}
.figure2 {
    animation: 20s company-slider infinite;
}
@keyframes company-slider {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    30% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    35% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    55% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    60% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    90% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    95% {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -300%;
    }
}
div#slider figure img {
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
/*div#slider figure:hover { animation-play-state:paused; }*/

div#slider li {
    list-style: none;
}
div#slider label {
    background-color: #111;
    bottom: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    width: .5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
#controls {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#control-container {
    padding: 25px 12%;
}
.control-button {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 25%;
    background: gray;
    height: 10px;
    border: none;
}
.control-button.active {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 25%;
    background: black;
    height: 10px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="slider">
    <figure class="figure figure2">
        <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
        <img src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.3376224.1450794847!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/4x3_620/tundra-tea-toss.jpg" alt>
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/22804/pexels-photo.jpg" alt>
        <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
    </figure>
    <div id="controls">
        <div id="control-container">
            <button id="slide1" class="control-button"></button>
            <button id="slide2" class="control-button"></button>
            <button id="slide3" class="control-button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are hundreds of slider plugins, why would you like to create another one? Looking at IDs and classes you use, you are on wrong direction - better check how other people did it.

Answer (score 2):

This makes all of the buttons active:

```
$('.control-button').addClass('active');
```

Replace it with:

```
$('.control-button').removeClass('active');
$(event.target).addClass('active');
```

Add the `event` parameter to the function so you can use `event.target`:

```
$('.control-button').click(function(event) {
```

---

**EDIT:**

Making the control buttons activate "naturally" as the images slide is a bit harder.

Make each image have an attribute that says which slide it is:

```
<figure class="figure figure2">
    <img data-number="slide1" src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
    <img data-number="slide2" src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.3376224.1450794847!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/4x3_620/tundra-tea-toss.jpg" alt>
    <img data-number="slide3" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/22804/pexels-photo.jpg" alt>
    <img data-number="slide4" src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
</figure>
```

Create a system to detect when the image comes into view:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
```

Detect which image is being shown:

```
    var activeImage = document.elementFromPoint($(window).width()/2, 10); // The image at the horizontal midpoint of the screen
```

Set the `class` of the corresponding control button to `active`:

```
    $('.control-button').removeClass('active');
    $("#"+$(activeImage).attr("data-number")).addClass('active'); // Sets whichever control button that corresponds to the image under the horizontal midpoint of the screen as active
```

Set how often you want to check at the closing of the `setInterval`:

```
}, /*time interval in miliseconds*/);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to get this to make the buttons active naturally as the slides change without having to click in them?

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as adding 'active' to all buttons you should replace this:

```
$('.control-button').addClass('active');
```

with this:

```
$('.control-button').removeClass('active');  //this removes all '.active' first
     $(this).addClass('active');
```

What's happening here is that within the .control-button click function, $(this) represents the current .control-button element.

Comment: How would it be removed then when I click another button?

Comment: Also do you know how I can make it so the control buttons are always showing an active button per slide that is displayed?

Comment: Right, I know I can use the `removeclass` property, but not sure how to structure it. Simply putting it over top of the add class doesn't work.

Comment: That's because there was a typo in the post: OP put `removeClass('.active')` and `addClass('active')`. The first one has a period before `active` which there's not supposed to be.

Comment: Yep, had a typo.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to get this to make the buttons active naturally as the slides change without having to click in them?

Comment: Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I would recommend using slick

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/q3j01xrs/ 
What about this? I improved your script. I took out your CSS animation and replaced it by another JavaScript animation. Have a look!

```
$('.control-button').click(function() {
  clearInterval(setInt);
  $('.control-button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var getIndex = $(this).index('.control-button');
  $('.figure img').hide();
  $('.figure img').eq(getIndex).show();
  setInt = setInterval(slide, 5000);
});

function slide() {
  var getIndex = $('.figure img:visible').index('.figure img');
  $('.control-button').removeClass('active');
  $('.figure img:visible').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 350);
  getIndex++;
  if ((getIndex) == $('.control-button').length) {
    $('.control-button').eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('.figure img').eq(0).animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 350);
  } else {
    $('.control-button').eq(getIndex).addClass('active');
    $('.figure img').eq(getIndex).animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 350);
  }
};
var setInt = setInterval(slide, 5000);
```